# execvp: bad address error

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec

I am working on linux to create a shell serving with various commands.
I have different built in commands and one of them is "history". 
I have a `reshist()` function to reset the array that contains the inputs entered by user.
I also want to enable system commands using `execvp()` and also multiple pipe operation.

`reshist()` function and multiple pipe operation works well when they are not together, but when I use them both, it causes `execvp()` to raise "bad address" error.

I know that reshist() function does not works correct to add inputs to the list, but that is not a big deal.
The problem is why I get the error.

What could be the reason? Any better ideas to make them work together?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER 129                       // max line buffer
#define MAX_ARGS 32                            // max # args
#define SEPARATORS " \t\n"                     // token sparators
char *args[MAX_ARGS];

int print[16];
int get[16];
int fd[2];

char histarr[10][129];  // History array
char histel[129];

void reshist(void)
{
  //HISTORY RESORTING

  int counter = 0;
  while (counter < 10)
  {  //shifting all elements by one from the last element of the list
    if (histarr[counter] == NULL )
    {
      strcpy(histarr[counter], histel); //first element of the history will contain the last command
      break;
    }
    counter++;
  }
  if (counter == 10)
  {
    counter = 1;
    while (counter < 10)
    {
      strcpy(histarr[counter - 1], histarr[counter]);
      counter++;
    }
    strcpy(histarr[9], histel);
  }

  memset(histel, 0, 127);
  //HISTORY RESORT ENDS
}

void setup(void)
{

  char buf[MAX_BUFFER];                      // line buffer
  //char * args[MAX_ARGS];                     // pointers to arg strings
  char ** arg;                               // working pointer thru args
  char * prompt = "333.sh>";                    // shell prompt

  /* keep reading input until "quit" command or eof of redirected input */

  while (!feof(stdin))
  {

    /* get command line from input */
    fputs(prompt, stdout);                // write prompt
    if (fgets(buf, MAX_BUFFER, stdin))
    { // read a line

      /* tokenize the input into args array */

      arg = args;
      *arg++ = strtok(buf, SEPARATORS);   // tokenize input
      while ((*arg++ = strtok(NULL, SEPARATORS)))
        ;
      // last entry will be NULL 

      strcpy(histel, buf);
      reshist();

      pid_t pid;
      int print[16];
      int get[16];
      int fd[2];

      int count = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while (args[i] != NULL )
      {
        if (0 == strcmp(args[i], "|"))
        {
          count++;
        }
        i++;
      }

      char *arrays[count + 1][i - count]; // array lines bordered as arrays[numberOfPipes+1][numberofArguments-numberOfPipes]

      i = 0;
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
      while (args[i] != NULL )
      {
        if (strcmp(args[i], "|") != 0)
        {
          arrays[x][y] = args[i]; //builting arrays that is going to be sent to the each process, each row of the matrix is an array to be sent to another process
          y++;
        }
        else
        {
          x++;
          y = 0;
        }
        i++;
      }

      int h = 0;
      int a = 0;
      int k = 0;
      for (k = 0; k <= count; k++)
      {

        get[k] = -1;
        print[k] = -1;
      }
      //create required number of pipes
      for (a = 0; a < count; a++)
      {
        if (pipe(fd) == -1)
        {
          perror("Pipe failure");
          continue;
        }
        get[a + 1] = fd[0];
        print[a] = fd[1];
      }

      for (k = 0; k <= count; k++)
      {

        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
        {
          printf("fork failed\n");
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
          if (print[k] != -1)
          {

            if (dup2(print[k], 1) == -1)
            {
              perror("dup2 error");
              exit(1);
            }
          }

          if (get[k] != -1)
          {

            if (dup2(get[k], 0) == -1)
            {
              perror("dup2read error");
              exit(1);
            }
          }

          for (h = 0; h <= count; h++)
          {
            close(print[h]);
            close(get[h]);
          }

          if (execvp((const char*) arrays[k][0], arrays[k]) < 1)
          {
            perror("error");
            exit(1);
          }

          exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
          int stat;
          close(print[k]);
          close(get[k]);
          waitpid(pid, &stat, 0);

        }

      }

    } // system command else ends         

  }
}

int main(void)
{
  setup();
  /**
   * After reading user input, the steps are:
   * (1) fork a child process using fork()
   * (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
   * (3) if command included &, parent will invoke wait()
   */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error?  Can you include this in your question?

Comment: Note that by the time `strtok()` has chopped it up, the `strcpy(histel, buf)` call will only copy the first word into `histel`. This is one of the reasons why some people (such as me) do not like or use `strtok()`.

Comment: And effectively the `while ((*arg++ = strtok(NULL, SEPARATORS)))
        ;` loop does nothing, except incrementing arg a few times and pointing it into the buffer. After the loop the buffer will be restored into its original state, and the pointers will point to substrings, all upto end of line. (indeed: strtok() is terrible)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The code seems to miss to `NULL`-terminate `arrays[k]`. Make the last entry in `arrays[k]` carry  `NULL`.

---

**Update**:

This

```
  if (execvp((const char*) arrays[k][0], arrays[k]) < 1)
```

should be

```
  if (execvp(arrays[k][0], arrays[k]) == -1)
```

of even more straight forward just:

```
  execvp(arrays[k][0], arrays[k]);
  perror("execvp() failed");
```

as the members of the `exec*()`-family of functions return on error *only*.